# Configure CMake to only run scons, not build anything

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, scons

I am using CLion (which only supports CMake) in a project using scons.

How can I configure  CMake to not build anything, just run scons with parameters, so IDE will be able to pickup up file references in errors and I will be able to navigate easily?

---

Edit1:
I have tried `add_custom_target` (suggested in comments) like this:

```
add_custom_target(game
        ALL
        scons p=linux bits=64
        SOURCES
        godot-cpp/godot_headers/android/godot_android.h
        godot-cpp/godot_headers/arvr/godot_arvr.h
        godot-cpp/godot_headers/gdnative/aabb.h
        godot-cpp/godot_headers/gdnative/array.h
... all files  from previously used add_executable (which worked with IDE)
)
```

But the IDE won't find any included files, so I am guessing I am doing something wrong. I also tried adding `COMMAND` before scons and various `WORKING_DIRECTORY` (`.`, `src`, without) without success.

Comment: Isn't `add_custom_target` what you're looking for?

Comment: [This thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205824609-Possible-to-have-CLion-build-a-project-with-an-external-command-e-g-make-) contains some tips for external build systems

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a [compilation database](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/compilation-database.html) from your `scons` build and have CLion consume that. I've used neither approaches though. (prefer CMake myself)

Comment: I have tried the `add_custom_target`, unsuccessfully (edited Q). I am a total noob in C++ and build tools, so I am not going to try to rewrite working build of a template project, because it would be a massive waste of time without any result :(. I barely made it working for a first time and that was a mostly prepared template... I just wanted IDE to work with error messages from compiler.

Comment: Please go ahead and vote for SCons support for CLion here:https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10591

Comment: It looks like you could create the compilation database by running scons under: https://github.com/nickdiego/compiledb

Comment: hey, any success for your question?

Comment: +1 I am running into this same problem with Godot-CPP, trying to setup a CMake build for my GDNative modules.

Answer (score 0):

SCons added the ability to generate compilation database file in recent releases.
So if you add this, or if Godot adds this to their SCons based build system, I think CLion should be able to find all the source files.